# Elasticsearch: Use `slop` parameter with Completion Suggester

Tags: java, python, elasticsearch, search, lucene

How can I use the [slop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html) parameter, or achieve the same functionality, with the [Completion Suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)?

An example use for this is if a User is typing the query `"Quick fox"`, and I have the document `"Quick Brown Fox"`, I want to be able to suggest the document `"Quick Brown Fox"`.

```
Documents: ["Quick Brown Fox", "Quick foxes", ...]

Query:
>> "Quick fox"

Results:
>> "Quick foxes"
>> "Quick Brown Fox"
>> ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, given the way that the completion suggester works (it just follows the common prefix) this wouldn't be possible. This job should be done by search instead.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7174

Comment: Yeah, having done some research into how the completion suggester is implemented using a [finite state transducer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html), it's pretty clear that this wouldn't be practical.